# How to check web application status written in Flash/Flex?

Tags: flash, security, service, status

I have a typical web application that communicates in the following way:

SWF file makes service calls to Java services (Remote object, over BlazeDS on Tomcat), which in turn communicates to database.

How do I implement a status check service (hosted on another domain) that will check if the ENTIRE app is up and running?

Ideally, I'd make checker SWF that would load App SWF and called its function that would return something from the database (a naive service would count rows in table and hash it with MD5), but security constrains won't let me call loaded SWF's function.

Checking the java services only is not enough, as I am not checking the status of the SWF.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to call a webpage with the flash on with a particular query string that will cause the flash to load and send a status message back - ie you call the flash indirectly through a webpage.

Comment: Thanks Josh, makes sense to me, but I am not sure I understood the implementation details:
An App web page should be called with a query string in URL, which will be understood by the swf and it will generate a status result accordingly, but how will it return the status message to the caller? Or, how that message would be caught? It would make sense if I checked it on the browser manually, it needs to be automatized as check should be performed every 3 minutes. Am I missing sthg?